# How to create a Twitter Bootstrap Textarea

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to create a Bootstrap Textarea with those shadow effects, etc in pure css, but I don't really know how to make it.

I have this code, but than I'm stucked:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
          border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
```

Can anyone tell me how to make it like bootstrap text area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HgcB8/)

Also transitions.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the textarea shadow by selecting it and adding the box-shadow css attribute. 
The syntax geos like this:

```
  box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;
```

in your case add:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
```